# Does functions in the main class have to be be included in the bracket of public static main? why

Tags: java, structure

This little error stop my program from running and I don't really understand why, I tried pretty much everything I can and follow all the fix that the program recommended for me but it will give me another error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MiddleString {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 


// this part basically take 3 strings as inputs 
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your first string");
    String str1 = in.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter your second string");
    String str2 = in.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter your third string");
    String str3 = in.next();

    System.out.println("The middle string is: " + comparison(str1, str2, str3))*;*     

   // the ";" at the end of the line above is where I get an error that it needs 
//1 more "}" to finish the method but it will give another error

   // this function should return the middle string out of 3 string inputs 

public static String comparison(String string1, String string2, String string3) {   

if((string1.compareTo(string2) < 0 && string1.compareTo(string3) > 0) || (string1.compareTo(string2) > 0) && string1.compareTo(string3) < 0) {
            return string1;

    }
    else if((string2.compareTo(string1) < 0 && string2.compareTo(string3) > 0) || (string2.compareTo(string1) > 0 && string2.compareTo(string3) < 0)) {

            return string2;
    }
    else if((string3.compareTo(string1) < 0 && string3.compareTo(string2) > 0) || (string3.compareTo(string1) > 0 && string3.compareTo(string2) < 0)) {

            return string3;
    }


   } 
}
```

Comment: 'It will give another error' such as what?

Comment: `System.out.println("The middle string is: " + comparison(str1, str2, str3))*;*` , remove `**`

Comment: i will give me an error on : comparison(String string1, String string2, String string3) :This method must return a result of type String

Comment: It just a sign to show where the error is John

Comment: And so it must. If none of the `if` and `else` conditions match, there is no value returned. So fix that. You should fix the errors in front of you, instead of just creating new ones and wondering why you can't fix those.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply missing the closing brace (`}`) at the end of your `main` method. Also, your method needs a default return statement because, if all three of your if statements evaluate false and thus do not execute, than the the thread will stop due to a lacking return statement and the program will also stop. Finally, I suggest that you use `in.nextLine();` instead of `in.next();`, because if the user enters a String with a space (E.g. `"Hello world"`), than the program will assign "Hello" to `str1` and "world" to `str2`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MiddleString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your first string");
        String str1 = in.nextLine(); //nextLine rather than next

        System.out.println("Please enter your second string");
        String str2 = in.nextLine(); //nextLine rather than next

        System.out.println("Please enter your third string");
        String str3 = in.nextLine(); //nextLine rather than next

        System.out.println("The middle string is: " + comparison(str1, str2, str3));
    } // Magical closing brace :O

    public static String comparison(String string1, String string2, String string3) {

        if ((string1.compareTo(string2) < 0 && string1.compareTo(string3) > 0) || (string1.compareTo(string2) > 0) && string1.compareTo(string3) < 0) {
            return string1;
        } else if ((string2.compareTo(string1) < 0 && string2.compareTo(string3) > 0) || (string2.compareTo(string1) > 0 && string2.compareTo(string3) < 0)) {
            return string2;
        } else if ((string3.compareTo(string1) < 0 && string3.compareTo(string2) > 0) || (string3.compareTo(string1) > 0 && string3.compareTo(string2) < 0)) {
            return string3;
        }
        return null; //Default return statement
    }
}
```

Comment: i will give me an error on : comparison(String string1, String string2, String string3)  :This method must return a result of type String

Comment: Did you include `return null;` at the end of the method?

Comment: oh wait, i did not, magicccc, any explanation :/, I don't really under stand why

Comment: @Jackkkkkk if all three of your if statements evaluate false and thus do not execute, than the the thread will stop due to a lacking return statement and the program will also stop.

Comment: @CardinalSystem What thread? The program won't even compile, let alone execute to the point of having any threads.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated above, 1 st problem: missing closing bracket '}' at the end of main(). 
 Second problem: your return statement was "optional" due to a 'gap' in condition block. When smallest and middle string are same value (compareTo() --> 0 ), all three conditions are 'false' thus no return and a parser error. 
Maybe you could rearrange your 'if' chunk using '<=' :

```
public static String comparison(String string1, String string2, String string3) {   

if(string1.compareTo(string2)<=0 && string1.compareTo(string3)<=0) { //1st smallest one
    if ( string2.compareTo(string3)<=0) return string2;  
    else return string3;
}else {  //1st  not smallest one
    if (string1.compareTo(string2)<=0 || string1.compareTo(string3)<=0) return string1;
    else if (string2.compareTo(string3)<=0) return string3;
    else return string2;
}
```

}